# Simple Genetic Algorithm meeting local optimum for "Hello World"

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm

My target was simple, using genetic algorithm to reproduce the classical "Hello, World" string.
My code was based on this [post](http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/).  The code mainly contain 4 parts:

1. Generate the population which has serval different individual
2. Define the fitness and grade function which evaluate the individual good or bad based on the comparing with `target`.
3. Filter the population and leave `len(pop)*retain` individuals
4. Add some other individuals and mutate randomly
5. The parents's DNA will pass over to its children to comprise the whole `population`.

I modified the code and shows like this:

```
import numpy as np
import string
from operator import add
from random import random, randint
def population(GENSIZE,target):
    p = []
    for i in range(0,GENSIZE):
        individual = [np.random.choice(list(string.printable[:-5])) for j in range(0,len(target))]
        p.append(individual)
    return p  

def fitness(source, target):
    fitval = 0
    for i in range(0,len(source)-1):
        fitval += (ord(target[i]) - ord(source[i])) ** 2
    return (fitval)    

def grade(pop, target):
    'Find average fitness for a population.'
    summed = reduce(add, (fitness(x, target) for x in pop))
    return summed / (len(pop) * 1.0)


def evolve(pop, target, retain=0.2, random_select=0.05, mutate=0.01):
    graded = [ (fitness(x, target), x) for x in p]
    graded = [ x[1] for x in sorted(graded)]
    retain_length = int(len(graded)*retain)
    parents = graded[:retain_length]
    # randomly add other individuals to
    # promote genetic diversity
    for individual in graded[retain_length:]:
        if random_select > random():
            parents.append(individual)
    # mutate some individuals
    for individual in parents:
        if mutate > random():
            pos_to_mutate = randint(0, len(individual)-1)
            individual[pos_to_mutate] = chr(ord(individual[pos_to_mutate]) + np.random.randint(-1,1))

    # 
    parents_length = len(parents)
    desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
    children = []
    while len(children) < desired_length:
        male = randint(0, parents_length-1)
        female = randint(0, parents_length-1)
        if male != female:
            male = parents[male]
            female = parents[female]
            half = len(male) / 2
            child = male[:half] + female[half:]
            children.append(child)
    parents.extend(children)
    return parents

GENSIZE = 40
target = "Hello, World"
p = population(GENSIZE,target)
fitness_history = [grade(p, target),]
for i in xrange(20):
    p = evolve(p, target)
    fitness_history.append(grade(p, target))
#     print p
for datum in fitness_history:
   print datum
```

But it seems that the result can't fit `target`well.

I tried to change the `GENESIZE` and loop time(more generation).
But the result always get stuck. Sometimes, enhance the loop time can help to find a optimum solution. But when I change the loop time to an much larger number like `for i in xrange(10000)`.  The result shows the error like:

```
    individual[pos_to_mutate] = chr(ord(individual[pos_to_mutate]) + np.random.randint(-1,1))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

Anyway, how to modify my code and get an good result.
Any advice would be appreciate.

Comment: You add a random integer to your char code. You should limit that to the range of valid (and printable) chars. What it tells you is that your arg has become < 0 or > 255.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem was the result never end like [this post](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2011/09/28/evolutionary-algorithm-evolving-hello-world/).

Comment: I did something similar a while back... but in js, might help see here --> https://github.com/gidili/WasDarwinWrong

Answer (score 0):

The `chr` function in Python2 only accepts values in the range 0 <= i < 256.

You are passing:

`ord(individual[pos_to_mutate]) + np.random.randint(-1,1)`

So you need to check that the result of

`ord(individual[pos_to_mutate]) + np.random.randint(-1,1)`

is not going to be outside that range, and take corrective action before passing to `chr` if it is outside that range.

**EDIT**

A reasonable fix for the ValueError might be to take the amended value modulo 256 before passing to `chr`:

`chr((ord(individual[pos_to_mutate]) + np.random.randint(-1, 1)) % 256)`

There is another bug: the fitness calculation doesn't take the final element of the candidate list into account: it should be:

```
def fitness(source, target):
    fitval = 0
    for i in range(0,len(source)):  # <- len(source), not len(source) -1
        fitval += (ord(target[i]) - ord(source[i])) ** 2
    return (fitval)
```

Given that source and target must be of equal length, the function can be written as:

```
def fitness(source, target):
    return sum((ord(t) - ord(s)) ** 2 for (t, s) in zip(target, source))
```

The real question was, why doesn't the code provided evolve random strings until the target string is reached.

The answer, I believe, is it may, but will take a lot of iterations to do so.

Consider, in the blog post referenced in the question, each iteration generates a child which replaces the least fit member of the gene pool if the child is fitter. The selection of the child's parent is biased towards fitter parents, increasing the likelihood that the child will enter the gene pool and increase the overall "fitness" of the pool.  Consequently the members of the gene pool converge on the desired result within a few thousand iterations.

In the code in the question, the probability of mutation is much lower, based on the initial conditions, that is the defaults for the `evolve` function.

1. Parents that are retained have only a 1% chance of mutating, and one third of the time the "mutation" will not result in a change (zero is a possible result of random.randint(-1, 1)).
2. Discard parents are replaced by individuals created by merging two retained individuals.  Since only 20% of parents are retained, the population can converge on a local minimum where each new child is effectively a copy of an existing parent, and so no diversity is introduced.

So apart from fixing the two bugs, the way to converge more quickly on the target is to experiment with the initial conditions and to consider changing the code in the question to inject more diversity, for example by mutating children as in the original blog post, or by extending the range of possible mutations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I miss something in my question. What't bother me more was the result never end with ["Hello, World]". When I loop for more generation, there was the error `chr() arg not in range(256)  `

Comment: So, my first attempt was to get an optimum result through GA programing.